# Jquery tab - add a class when active

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm trying to edit this:

http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/HznC9/3/

As you can see the code add the class "current_tab" at "ul.tab_nav li a" clicked.

I need to add this class at "ul.tab_nav li".

I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.tabs').each(function(){
    var tab = $(this);
    tab.find('.tab_content').hide(); // Hide all divs

    tab.find('ul.tab_nav li').click(function(){ //When any link is clicked
        if($(this).hasClass('current_tab')) return false;
        tab.find('ul.tab_nav li').removeClass('current_tab');
        $(this).addClass('current_tab'); //Set clicked link class to active

        var currentTab = tab.find($(this).attr('href')); // Set variable currentTab to value of href attribute of clicked link

        tab.find('.tab_content').hide(); // Hide all divs
        $(currentTab).slideDown(); // Show div with id equal to variable currentTab
        return false;
    });
});
});
```

But in this way the "tab_content" not will be shown.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your click event handler *this* refers to a `<li>` element, but your *href* attribute is on a child `<a>` element:

```
<li><a href=".tab2"class="iconTab iconTabWifi">&nbsp;</a></li>
```

So instead of doing this:

```
var currentTab = tab.find($(this).attr('href'));
```

do this:

```
var currentTab = tab.find($(this).find("a.iconTab").attr('href'));
```